# Can I run Busybox without having an OS installed on the machine?

Tags: linux, kernel, busybox

I understand that Busybox is a single executable file that contains a set of unix commands/utilities.

My question is do we need an underlying OS on which it will run or it can be run directly on the machine without a kernel. If it can be run without an explicit OS, who will handle the stuff like CPU scheduling, user & role management, etc. And in case it needs an underlying OS, how can it be platform agnostic?

Please help me understand what I am missing here?

Edit:

So the root of the confusion was, I read that it is installed on small embedded devices. What I conclude is that these devices should come with some lightweight OS installed on top of which we can add basic unix functionalities with busybox.

Also by platform-agnostic above, I mean underlying OS agnostic. For example, can I run BusyBox over windows and if so how can that be possible?

Comment: No it can't. Busybox is not that special. It's just a normal user application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If it can be run without an explicit OS, who will handle the stuff like CPU scheduling, user & role management, etc.

That should answer your first question already: Those are things a kernel does, and without kernel, programs that rely on those features just cannot run, which includes busybox.

As for a platform agnostic kernel, that's easier said than done. I assume by platform you mean processor architecture, which means you want an executable that runs without any VM in between on any processor which is just not possible.

The closest thing to what you want might be some minimalist linux distro, like core linux (only 11 MB).

If you don't want any user interaction after booting, you could even throw out some more stuff from the OS, but I assume you'd want at least a terminal so you can interact with the system.

---

> So the root of the confusion was, I read that it is installed on small embedded devices. What I conclude is that these devices should come with some lightweight OS installed on top of which we can add basic unix functionalities with busybox.

There's several aspects to this question:

- What even is an embedded device? These days you can easily run a full linux distribution on a raspberry pi, which is technically still a "small embedded device", and you can obviously run busybox on that to make it more lightweight. I suspec that's what that quote refers to.
- You could probably modify busybox to run without a kernel; how difficult of a task that would be depends on how much it relies on kernel calls and whether you want all of its features to work or just a few of them.
- How much sense does it even make? Busybox implements several programs described in the POSIX standard, which are meant to be used in combination with a unix-like kernel. For example, what's the point of `chroot` when you don't even have a filesystem, let alone a root directory?

> Also by platform-agnostic above, I mean underlying OS agnostic. For example, can I run BusyBox over windows and if so how can that be possible?

Yes but no; Windows has a different API for programs to interact with the kernel. It also uses a different binary format for executable files. There's no way to just run busybox on windows without some sort of compatibility layer.

Normally you'd use something like mingw for that, which essentially implements linux APIs in such a way that they are redirected to the corresponding windows APIs under the hood. This allows you to compile and run simple linux programs without any major modifications to the source code.

Since Windows 10, microsoft also provides one such compatibility layer themselves, with *Windows Subsystem for Linux*, which afaik. now runs an entire virtualized linux kernel *within windows* to run linux applications "natively".

Comment: This is helpful. Can you stretch your answer a little bit to help me understand what I have added in the edit. From platform-agnostic I meant underlying OS agnostic.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the definition of OS:

It needs the kernel, but does not need the rest of the OS.
The kernel (Linux) is the smaller part of the OS (Gnu/Linux, in most Unix like systems that use Linux). You can use busybox/Linux: that is just busybox and Linux (no Gnu, no anything).

Comment: this may be relevant https://superuser.com/q/307087/62123

Comment: this was really helpful.

Comment: In a sense, busybox *is* part of the OS

Comment: busybox is linking to the standard C library and is assuming A LOT of non standard stuff about it. I had trouble to get its `nslookup` applet to work on android, since it's poking directly into and making assumptions about the (undocumented) layout of the structs used by the implementation of gethostbyname().  And that was just the tip of the iceberg. Saying that it only needs a linux kernel is purely philosophical

Comment: @pizdelect If you statically link it then it won't need external libraries. Does it have other dependencies?

Comment: that doesn't matter. you can also embed the initramfs in the kernel image (as many systems do): that doesn't mean that there no longer is any userland. Busybox is a normal userland program, it assumes an OS, library, a populated fs, etc: it just packs multiple programs together for reasons of space And besides, static executables are not really supported with the GNU C library: you will need to use musl or glibc if you don't want to depend on any shared .so objects.

Comment: s/glibc/uclibc/ above